# C++ pointers difference between * and ->

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++: ptr->hello(); /* VERSUS */ (*ptr).hello();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447543/c-ptr-hello-versus-ptr-hello)

Too bad I can't google this...

Could someone explain or point me to where I can find the difference between these two? I understand * is a dereferencing operator, what about the -> ? What's the difference?

Comment: i fear answering this due to your rep points inflicting curses

Comment: @Shredder or the fear of not answering it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a->b` is a syntactic sugar for `(*a).b`

The only special case is the object `operator->` which is called when -> is used on an object. It can be used to "simulate" the object is a pointer ( as with smart references )

Comment: (*a).b is syntactic sugar for a->b.

Answer (score 4):

In the absence of overloading `operator->`, `p->x` is equivalent to `(*p).x`