# Difference between Pointer->Call() and (*Pointer).Call()

Tags: c++, function, pointers, call, dereference

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ptr->hello(); /* VERSUS */ (*ptr).hello();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/447543/ptr-hello-versus-ptr-hello)

I am learning C++ and my question is if there is any difference between using the arrow operator (`->`) or dereferencing the pointer `*` for calling a function.

These two cases illustrate my question.

```
Class* pointer = new Class();
(*pointer).Function();         // case one
pointer->Function();           // case two
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that my question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/447543/ptr-hello-versus-ptr-hello and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681926/c-pointers-difference-between-and?rq=1. I am sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given

```
Class* pointer = new Class();
```

Then

```
(*pointer).Function();         // case one
```

dereferences the pointer, and calls the member function `Function` on the referred to object. It does not use any overloaded operator. Operators can't be overloaded on raw pointer or built-in type arguments.

```
pointer->Function();           // case two
```

This does the same as the first one, using the built-in `->` because `pointer` is a *raw pointer*, but this syntax is better suited for longer chains of dereferencing.

Consider e.g.

```
(*(*(*p).pSomething).pSomethingElse).foo()
```

versus

```
p->pSomething->pSomethingElse->foo()
```

The `->` notation is also more obvious at a glance.

Answer (score 6):

If the operators `*` and `->` aren't overloaded, both versions accomplish the same.